# iOS - Device, if muted, hangs when setting kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, mute

I have an issue where I'm trying to change my Audio Category on AVAudioSession, to start recording microphone input.

If I do this with my current implementation (and lots of alternative implementations, to try and solve this issue) when the device's mute switch is not set (i.e. unmuted), then everything's fine.

If I do this when muted - coming from any prior audio category (MediaPlayback, SoloAmbient etc.), there's a huge delay, and it results in the device behaving very sluggish for a while.

Here's what I'm doing. On app startup, I do this:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbient;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

and later, to start recording:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

If I debug and step through, everything's as fast as expected until I hit AudioSessionSetProperty - that's where the device is hanging. It happens when I use either of the RecordAudio and PlayAndRecord categories.

When this happens, I get the following messages in the console:

```
AudioSessionSetProperty posting message to kill mediaserverd
AudioSessionSetActive posting message to kill mediaserverd
AudioQueueSetProperty posting message to kill mediaserverd
AllocateBuffer posting message to kill mediaserverd
```

I've searched online for these but they are never reported alongside this kind of delay I'm experiencing, and they also don't highlight what I might be doing wrong.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, and do you know what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance